Why is my copy rotation constraint causing strange behavior
When I try to rotate the foot using the target bone, the X and Z axis transform incorrectly. I know the image doesn't provide much info, but I hope you can understand what the issue is. Either the target bone rotates in the wrong way, or the foot bone itself rotates the wrong way which is even worse. I have tried to delete and re-apply the copy rotation. The copy Y rotation constraint option seems to be working fine. 

hello, you could simply parent the foot to the controller, also maybe you need to invert the rotation? Please share your file?
